# Spring boot Kafka doesn't work - consumer not receiving messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run a simple Spring Boot Kafka application but I can't make it work. I've followed various tutorials, now I'm implementing [this one](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-consume-producer-example/), but when I start the application this is what happens:

[image]

I can write in the console, but the consumer doesn't receive any message.
This is my SpringApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.springmiddleware")
@ComponentScan("com.springmiddleware")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("com.springmiddleware")
public class SpringMiddlewareApplication implements CommandLineRunner{



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringMiddlewareApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Autowired
    private Producer sender;

    @Override 
    public void run (String... strings) {
        sender.send("Hello world");
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:8080

app:
  topic:
    foo: foo.t

logging:
  level:
    root: ERROR
    org.springframework.web: ERROR
    com.memorynotfound: DEBUG
```

Consumer class, Producer Class and their configurations' class are the same as written in the tutorial.
In my server.properties file I have:

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:8080
```

and in zookeeper.properties:

```
clientPort=8080
```

Same port specified in application.yml. Before starting the application, I run

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

and

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
```

**UPDATE**

This is the `ReceiverConfig` class:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "foo");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

This is the SenderConfig class:

```
    @Configuration
public class SenderConfig {


    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

And this is the method `listen` that is in the Consumer class

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic.foo}")
    public void listen(@Payload String message) {
        System.out.println("Received " + message);
    }
```

Producer class:

```
@Service
public class Producer {

     @Autowired
     private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

     @Value("${app.topic.foo}")
        private String topic;

     public void send(String message){
            kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
        }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

> [2019-04-01 17:23:52,492] INFO Established session 0x100435950880000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60079 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,539] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0xef txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,555] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xf0 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,555] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xf1 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/topics (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,555] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xf2 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/changes Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/changes (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,570] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x5 zxid:0xf3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/delete_topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /admin/delete_topics (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,570] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0xf4 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/seqid Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/seqid (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,586] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x7 zxid:0xf5 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/isr_change_notification Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /isr_change_notification (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,586] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x8 zxid:0xf6 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/latest_producer_id_block Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /latest_producer_id_block (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,586] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0xf7 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/log_dir_event_notification Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /log_dir_event_notification (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,602] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0xa zxid:0xf8 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/topics (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,602] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0xb zxid:0xf9 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/clients Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/clients (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,617] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0xc zxid:0xfa txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/users Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/users (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:52,617] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:create cxid:0xd zxid:0xfb txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/brokers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-04-01 17:23:53,564] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100435950880000 type:multi cxid:0x3a zxid:0xff txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)

Comment: show the consumer config and producer configs class with listener method

Comment: Updated with the classes

Comment: @Deadpool mate that line is correct. KafkaTemplate is used within the `Producer` class's method.

Comment: Can you please add the `Producer` class?

Comment: @MadhuBhat added the producer class in question

Comment: The `Producer` might be sending the message. Add `LOG.info("sending message='{}' to topic='{}'", message, topic);` to the `send` method of `Producer` and see if it prints that while starting the spring boot app.

Comment: @MadhuBhat unfortunately nothing is printed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **application.yml**, you have specified the **zookeeper port** instead of the **kafka broker port**

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:8080
```

In the above, you should be defining the port of the **kafka broker**, ie the value of `port=` of the **server.properties** file.

A Spring boot app runs by default on port **8080**, so please don't use the same for Zookeeper port, unless you have changed the default port of the Spring boot app.

So in the **server.properties**, have `port=9092` and `zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181`, and in the **application.yml**, have as below:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

Then in the **zookeeper.properties**, have `clientPort=2181`. Then restart the Zookeeper, the Kafka server and the Spring boot app in the same order.

**Update:**

Newer versions of Kafka uses `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` instead of `port=9092` in the server.properties file. So try replacing that.

Comment: Hi, in server.properties file I do not have port=, do I have to add it manually? In which position should it be?

Comment: @TodorokiM the `server.properties` should have a `port` key to define on which port the kafka broker should run on. Check out this sample properties file https://github.com/bkimminich/apache-kafka-book-examples/blob/master/config/server.properties

Comment: Add `port=9092` to the `server.properties`, add the same port to `spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:` of the `application.yml`, then restart the zookeeper, kafka server and your spring boot app.

Comment: Hi, I've tried what you've said but the application is stuck at the same point

Comment: @TodorokiM What does the console log of the spring boot app say?

Comment: Nothing, it just freezes at Spring startup with the Spring title. After a while it throws a TimeOutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Comment: @TodorokiM have the zookeeper and kafka started correctly?

Comment: okay, on which port spring boot app is running?, zookeeper port? and kafka server port?

Comment: Spring boot is running on port 8080, while the other two on 2181

Comment: @TodorokiM change the zookeeper port to 2181 in `zookeeper.connect=localhost:8080` and `clientPort=8080`, the kafka port to `9092` in `spring: kafka: bootstrap-servers:` and `port=`. Then restart zookeeper, kafka and the spring boot app.

Comment: don't mess up with ports default kafka server `port=9092` default zookeeper `port=2181` and default tomcat `port:8080` leave them like that @TodorokiM

Comment: @MadhuBhat changed like that but still doing nothing :\

Comment: @TodorokiM I have updated my answer with the steps in order. Can you confirm that you have done the same?

Comment: @MadhuBhat Yes, I've done exactly like that. I've updated my question with an error that is now giving me the zookeeper run

Comment: @TodorokiM can you try with replacing `port=9092` to `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` in the `server.properties` and restarting zookeeper, kafka and spring boot app ?

Comment: @MadhuBhat it works this way! Thanks! What is the difference?

Comment: @TodorokiM the older Kafka version used `port=`, but the newer one uses `listeners=`, that's the difference.

Comment: @MadhuBhat thank you, if you edit your answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: @TodorokiM updated my answer. Happy to be of help :)